# Django: model testing setUp get test record insert id

Tags: database, django, django-models

I'm new on testing Django applications but I feel there should be some sort of internal framework method to retrieve last insert id.

How to get last insert id?

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific way of getting the last insert id, but when inserting you get the entire object including the id.

```
new_instance = models.SomeModel(foo='something', bar='something else')
new_instance.save()
print new_instance.pk

new_instance = models.SomeModel.objects.create(foo='something', bar='something else')
print new_instance.pk
```

Comment: What if I use SomeModel.objects.create() method?

Comment: @sultan: I've added an example for the `create` aswell.